# Spock timing issue with running Platform.runLater() in "when" block

Tags: java, javafx, groovy, thread-safety, spock

If a method has to be called in the JavaFX thread, it appears that I have to do the following in my `when` block:

```
... setup ...
// def throwable

when:
Platform.runLater( new Runnable(){
    @Override
    void run() {
        // try {
        log.debug "in runnable, calling run method ..."
        someObject.methodWhichMustRunInJavaFXThread()
        log.debug "... run method finished normally"
        // }catch( Throwable t ){
        //     log.error( t.message, t )
        //     throwable = t
        // }
    }
})
WaitForAsyncUtils.waitForFxEvents()
log.debug "waitForFXEvents ended..."
// if throwable != null 
//     throw throwable
/* NB it appears that re-throwing the Throwable like this after waitForFxEvents
is probably the only way to bring it to the developer's attention! 
PS I added this re-throwing idea only a few hours after submitting the question. I am 
currently monitoring things to find whether this in fact solves the problem */

then:
// throwable == null 
/* in fact this seems to be a rather naive check: from my experimentation, 
regardless of whether caught in the above catch clause, it appears that if a throwable
is thrown in `run`, although "invocation counting tests" are performed in the "then" 
block, this sort of "static" equality check will never be performed in the "then" block
*/
... other verifications...
```

But I find, intermittently, that such a technique can lead to a horrible leakage of a failure to a subsequent test if an exception is thrown in the `run` method. I thought that attempting to catch any such throwables, as shown in the above code if you uncomment all the comment lines, might solve the problem, but in fact no: a throwable thrown in `run`, and caught by the `catch` clause, can still be attributed to a later method!

This is an example of the kind of misleading Spock fail output: although this NPE is thrown in a `Platform.runLater( ... )` in a previous test method (in fact in a completely different `Specification` in the file initial_load_testing.groovy), this failure is actually attributed to a test which happens to come some arbitrary time after it.

NB note the mention of a "Delayed Exception"...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setRoot() on null object
    at org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils.---- Delayed Exception: (See Trace Below) ----(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:0)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setRoot() on null object
    at core.FileHandlingFramework.tryToLoadFile(filehandlingframework.groovy:83)
    at core.StdFileHandlingFrameworkTemplate.tryToOpenFile(stdfilehandlingframeworktemplate.groovy:97)
    at core.App.start(main.groovy:120)
    at core.AppStdSpec2$1.run(initial_load_testing.groovy:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

What I find strange is that I have, precisely, allowed JavaFX thread events to "bubble up" with `WaitForAsyncUtils.waitForFxEvents()` ... and yet it seems that somehow the throwing of a throwable can sometimes be detected by the Spock framework AFTER this `waitForFXEvents()` method ends.

Is there a solution to this? The intermittent nature of the phenomenon is a real problem.

Comment: A note that even Java has lambdas now; Groovy has had them for ages. `Platform.runLater { print 'hello world' }`. (This won't fix your problem.) I haven't worked with JavaFX, but in similar async cases I've used a `CountdownLatch` and `await`ed in the `when` block.

Comment: Yup, cool. Any thoughts about the phenomenon? Later: OK `CountdownLatch`: makes sense, possibly, although my assumption, from the name alone (!) is that `waitForFxEvents()` should be that latch.

Comment: The problem is somewhere inside the JavaFX dispatching domain (possibly including your wait-utils). Past that, not nearly familiar enough to say.

Comment: @mikerodent, as always here - and even though you permanently refuse to comply - I kindly advise you to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) consisting of more than just code snippets. Give everyone here a mini project with build configuration, a little application + test in order to reproduce the issue. You really seem to like people making speculative guesses instead of directly answering your question, which is why you end up getting no answers and using bad workarounds.

Comment: @kriegaex We've had this discussion before. A few days ago kleopatra asked me for an MCE (https://stackoverflow.com/q/61561250/595305), which I duly did. But in fact there was no need for an MCE in that case, for James_D to be able to answer, and I'm sure there is no need for one here. An MCE is not appropriate for every question, and if you look at random questions you will see that most people don't provide one. You could help me by saying whether you have in fact used `Platform.runLater` in your `when` blocks. If you have, and never experienced "over-running" (a fail being reported ...

Comment: ... in a later test), that would be interesting. It is an intermittent problem, which occurs without consistency or reproducibility. It is clearly something to do with using the JavaFX thread in a normal Spock `Specification` (i.e. I get this without using TestFX `ApplicationSpec`). In posing this question I was hoping someone might say "ah yes, that happened to me, and this is the solution". I suspect few people ever use `Platform.runLater` in their `when` blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help, and I will try to think one up. It won't be trivial to do so because I'll have to make sure that this phenomenon occasionally occurs. The context in which it occurs is multiple tests, 10s of tests (around 200+ unit tests currently). It could take some time!

Answer (score 0):

Provisionally, the following solution *appears* to work, by rethrowing any exception caught in the FX thread before the `when` block ends:

```
void executeInFXThreadAndWait( def closure, def ... params ){
    Throwable fXThrowable
    Platform.runLater({ 
        try {
            closure(params)
        }catch( Throwable t ){
            if( t.message != 'exit' ) {
                log.error(t.message, t)
                fXThrowable = t
            }
        }
    })
    WaitForAsyncUtils.waitForFxEvents()
    if( fXThrowable != null ){
        // add calling trace so fail trace identifies Specification line concerned
        fXThrowable.stackTrace += Thread.currentThread().stackTrace
        throw fXThrowable
    }
}
```

Usage (`App` extends `Application`):

```
...
def myClosure = { args ->
    App.instance.start( args[ 0 ] )
}
...

when:
TestUtilities.instance.executeInFXThreadAndWait( myClosure, mockStage )

then:
...
```

NB the thing about testing for "exit" is that sometimes I deliberately throw an exception in a test to "eject" from a method where what needed to be verified has already been verified. If the `Throwable`'s message is "exit" it gets ignored.

Hypothesis: I am guessing, without knowing, that the Spock framework is able to detect whether an exception has been "dealt with", and that if it is rethrown like this the framework will not then follow up with a "Delayed Exception". Spock experts' comments welcome.

**Later**
A few days later: the verdict seems to be that this improves things. However, it can still happen, without any apparent predictability or consistency, that fails from one Specification and feature are reported under another Specification and feature. Each time this has happened, another run of the same tests happens without such spurious errors.

I believe that Spock makes no claims about being able to deal with concurrent programming. It'd be nice to know whether anyone else has ever experienced this phenomenon when doing `Platform.runLater` in the `when` block.