# Make multiple change firings lead to far fewer actions

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, changelistener

I have a `TextArea` in which the user of my app can write things. A `ChangeListener` is also listening to the `StringProperty` "text" of this `TextArea`. Whenever the text content changes, `ChangeListener.changed()`, among other things, sets a "dirty" `BooleanProperty` to `true` on a central app object. Where "dirty" has the sense of "document needs saving".

But I've just implemented a thing in my app whereby any time that the "dirty" `Property` gets set to `true` triggers a save-file-to-disk action, automatically, so the user doesn't have to worry about manually saving things. NB the act of saving also sets `dirty` back to `false` of course.

One problem with this is, though, that it slows typing in the `TextArea` (particulary as this saving takes place on the FX thread). Each new character added or deleted therefore fires a save action.

I want to find a solution where every single change-of-text action is always followed by a save at most within, say, 1 second, but where saving never happens more than once per this 1 second ... obviously in a non-FX thread.

This isn't the first time I've encountered this situation and in the past I've tinkered with various queues of timers, and so on. But it's difficult to find a solution where both criteria are met and I'm just wondering if there's a well-known technique to deal with this... even maybe something from some library?

Here's an MRE/MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    BooleanProperty dirty;
    void setDirty(Boolean value) {
        dirtyProperty().set(value);
        if( value ){
            System.out.println( "serialise to file again...");
            // successful saving also means we become clean again:
            dirtyProperty().set( false );
        }
    }
    Boolean getDirty() { return dirtyProperty().get(); }
    BooleanProperty dirtyProperty() {
        if ( dirty == null) dirty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "dirty");
        return dirty;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        Group sceneRoot = (Group)scene.getRoot();
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        textArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String t1) {
                setDirty( true );
            }
        });

        sceneRoot.getChildren().add( textArea );
        stage.setMinWidth( 600 );
        stage.setMinHeight( 400 );
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Each keystroke causes a save...

Comment: Thanks. I'll try putting one together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using background threads, use a pause transition:

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
    // save action here
});

dirtyProperty().addListener((obs, wasDirty, isNowDirty) -> {
    if (isNowDirty && pause.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
        pause.playFromStart();
    }
});
```

This will start the one-second pause when the `dirtyProperty()` changes to true, and at the end of the pause, will save the data. However, by checking the status of the pause, it will not schedule more than one save per second.

If you do want to use background threads, you can do something along the following lines:

```
BlockingQueue<String> textToSave = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
    try {
        String text = textToSave.take();
        // save text
    } catch (InterruptedException interrupt) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and then

```
dirtyProperty().addListener((obs, wasDirty, isNowDirty) -> {
    textToSave.clear();
    textToSave.offer(myTextArea.getText());
});
```

This assumes no threads other than the FX Application Thread is pushing data to the `textToSave` "queue" (not sure if something of size <= 1 is properly called a "queue"), which seems easy enough to ensure.

The advantage of this approach is that the IO happens on a background thread, which means there's no opportunity whatsoever to block the FX Application Thread by writing the file.

Comment: Thanks. But I believe this falls into a (potential) nasty concurrency trap of various solutions which I've tried before. Say you are typing "happily away blah": at "h" the `PauseTransition` starts... and say you finish typing "away" before the second is up. The "save action" looks at the current text content and saves accordingly. But by then you have typed your "blah"... but because the `PauseTransition`'s status is not updated in the JavaFX thread you are (probably) left with "clean" despite the fact that "blah" has now been typed.

Comment: @mikerodent There's no concurrency at all. Everything here happens on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: OK, well that's great then. Thanks.

Comment: @mikerodent (Basically, the way animations work is that they simply register themselves with the JavaFX Application thread. On each "pulse" of the FX Application thread (typically 60 times per second), the FX Application Thread checks if each animation needs to do anything, so in this case on the first pulse that happens after 1 second expires, it will execute the `onFinished` handler, on the FX Application Thread. Event handlers (which you use to update the `dirtyProperty()`) are executed on the same thread, so can't happen asynchronously to this.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had heard about these JavaFX "pulses" but had no idea at all what they were about. As I say I've previously tried finding a solution to this problem (in Swing) but basically it's always involved me banging my head against a brick wall. Of course it is possible to set up your own "pulse" using `Timer.schedule()` ... but your solution is far more elegant (and thread-safe).

Comment: @mikerodent Added a threading version for completeness. It does carry some advantages (though the code is more complex).

Comment: Thanks again... I was thinking of just spawning a non-FX thread in `pause.setOnFinished()`. Sorry to be slightly sceptical again, but doesn't the fact that you `clear` the queue here with each `changed` event mean that if you type continuously you could in fact wait for a long time before a save happened? Or am I being naive (again)?

Comment: @mikerodent I don't think so (but I may be wrong). If the background thread is invoked after `clear()` but before the `offer()`, then it will block until something is available. After `offer()` it should receive a `notify()`  which means it'll be able to receive the new value before the next `clear()`. I suppose if you have multiple threads polling the queue it's possible one will get stuck always being unlucky enough to poll between `clear()` and `offer()`. I edited (but rolled back) with a version that uses an `AtomicReference` instead of the queue, but I think this is correct.

Comment: Confirmed: both solutions work very nicely. Continuous typing with solution #2 is not a problem: a save happens each second. Great stuff.